# Cannot step through code while debugging android NDK project

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-debug

I am trying to learn how to use ffmpeg for android, and am trying setup this project to start with: https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg

It worked great with a few URLs I tried. I then compiled ffmpeg with mms protocol and wma support, and tried to open one media. The player returns cannot open media with error code -1. I can see it read the headers of the media in the logcat. I tried to debug and see why it gives me error, so I put a breakpoint @ jni_player_set_data_source function in player.c file. I followed [these instructions](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/) to start ndk debugging in eclipse. After a few tries, it reached the breakpoint and I could continue or stop at the breakpoints in native code. But I cannot step in through the code, and cannot see the values of the variables. I put three breakpoints in that functions, I can step from one breakpoint to another, but thats about all I can do. How can I step through the code and more see the values of the variables?

- I have FFMpegLibrary project setup as "is library" in eclipse.
- The FFMpegExample uses FFMpegLibrary
- I am debugging FFMpegExample as "Android application"
- I am then letting the jni libs to load and then run ndk-gdb-eclipse
- Then I go back to eclipse and start debugging the FFMpegLibrary native debug configuration. Then I can hit F8 on the java debug, and the execution stops at the native code. I can press F8 again to go to next native code's breakpoint but I cannot do F5, F6 or F7 (any code stepping) there. The icons for those are diabled in the toolbar.

Please let me know if you need more information to understand my setup.

Comment: Having the exact same problem, F5, F6 and F7 do nothing, only F8 stops on breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on trying to debug that code further and used Vitamio library. If you are just looking for some mediaplayer library for android which supports more formats and protocols than default media player library, use [Vitamio bundle](http://vitamio.org/vitamios?locale=en). I dont know how the license works though. I just needed to test something, so, i did not bother to find it out. Please share your experiences if you manage to make the debugging work though.